# Easy and efficient way of breaking up html code into several files and using php's include()

Tags: php, html, include

Currently, for things like a header, footer or common sidebar object, I create a custom `.php` file and do something along these lines:

```
echo '
    <some><html><here>
';
```

and then include it on the pages that I want it to appear:

```
include('path/to/file');
```

The only problem with this is that someone can point their browser to my `.php` file and view part of html on its own. It isn't a huge deal, but it seems unprofessional and a little careless. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: We had a related question just minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189834/phpdefined-or-exit

Comment: @vascowhite That's a link to the current question... what's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to move all those files outside the `DocumentRoot` / `public` directory and include them from there. Something like:

```
include '../pages/header.php';
// rest of the script
include '../pages/bottom.php';
```

Anyway that's the purpose of that directory - to only hold things that are meant to be accessed directly.

Of course, the first step after this would be to look into having only one index.php file which filters all the requests (permissions, filtering, rewrites, etc) and includes whatever is necessary based on the request (this is called a Front Controller and there are also a few lightweight frameworks which already implement it). Here's a starting point: https://github.com/adrian-gheorghe/basic-website/blob/master/public/index.php

Comment: This seems like it shouldn't be too hard to implement as I haven't gone too far with my website. Also, thanks for mentioning "Front Controllers", didn't know they existed.

Comment: @MaxMackie I've added a link to a basic implementation which I'm using for a few websites, maybe you'll be able to steal some ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the included php files in a separate directory, and make this directory inaccessible from the outside (using .htaccess with Apache, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You must restrain the access to other files in the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress pretty much does what you are currently doing: it stores all of the theme files in `/wp-content/themes/THEMENAMEHERE/`, and you can access the files to there directly. It's not that big of a concern, as users can't exactly do anything harmful, but if you care, you can store your files in a separate directory (as other answers have mentioned), or configure `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` to block access to the particular scripts.