# Disallow direct access

Tags: php, security, brute-force

Basically, I have two files, in two different directories: index.php (in /login/) and index.php(in /login/buyer/) .

**The /login/buyer/ index.php file has:**

```
<?php
session_start();

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){
        echo "<a href='../logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

**The /login/ index.php file has:**

```
<!--

an form to login

-->

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){ #user has logged in by creating a session var
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
?>
```

These two files seem to be working fine, but say for instance a malicious user wants to try to directly access `/login/buyer/` without providing an credentials and wants to just try that at the end of the url like `mysite.com/login/buyer`, instead of logging in. How can I add another condition in there to stop this?

Comment: Isn't the `if(!isLoggedIn()){ header(); die(); }` part enough?

Comment: I agree with @Robus, a user who hasn't logged in properly from your /index.php file won't be able to access the content in the /login/buyer/index.php file because you check so the session is set

Comment: Yeah, but if i try to just visit... /login/buyer/ without logging in via the url it just hangs for awhile, but never actually do anything. I dont want the server hanging... i want it to do something

Comment: Are there any additional security measures I should be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a single `/index.php` file (that is, a "**controller**") for all web accesses.

This way, you have to check once for all files if the session is valid or not.

Use parameters to tell which "**module**" and "**action**" (Symfony 1.x vocabulary) you want to proceed.

E.g. `yoursite.com/index.php?module=user&action=login&type=buyer`, or better with a **.htaccess** and a routing engine: `yousite.com/user/login/buyer`

As I suggest [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189834/phpdefined-or-exit-at-the-beginning-of-many-files/8189907#8189907), it is even better to put the `index.php` and the other source files (which should not be accessed directly through the webserver), in separate directories.

**Additional advice**:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

could be simply rewritten to:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do this all in an object?

Comment: I guess you mean "is it possible to do this all in one single `index.php` file"?

Comment: No, basically want would be nice to have is an object for 'sessions only' that I can reuse on any pages requiring sessions. Following me now?

Comment: You can then directly use your `$_SESSION` array, or create a `Session` class with specific methods like `Session::isLoggedIn()` for repetitive checks/process.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for a valid session on every page.

It looks like your code does that (though my PHP is rusty).

If it's matter of someone who is not a buyer logging in and then using the buyer page, you need to associate permissions / roles with each type of account and check for appropriate permissions where needed.

For example, on the buyer page, you could have something like

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'] && isset('isBuyer') && $_SESSION['isBuyer'])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You would have to populate $_SESSION['isBuyer'] at the time of logon, based on the provided user ID.

Comment: Is the `$_SESSION['isBuyer']` part really need if it redirects them to say... `/login/buyer/profile/` upon successful  login are sent using `header()` to the /profile/ subdirectory??

Answer (score 0):

It's considered ultimate security to force the user to log-in AGAIN before reaching the actual payment page or buyer index.

That's because true authorization information is not safe in session variables, as the session ID, which PHP uses to identify each user, is passed by either the GET variables (in the URL) or as a cookie. Both are very easy to steal over an unsecured network or XSS vulnerabilities.

You should have an SSL encrypted login page IN ADDITION to the session check to make sure the user is logged in before entering the critical area in your website.

Comment: Yes, I plan on using the highest grade SSL, but the development is not there yet.

Comment: The point of /buyer/ is to show account settings. This isnt dealing with payments (yet) :) . How do I secure this further in regards to XSS? SSL will definitely be implemented